# При декодировании текста методом Base64, содержащего русские буквы, выводится неверный результат

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

Хотя на сайте http://crypt-online.ru/crypts/base64/ всё дешифруется верно.
Вот пример кода:

```
import base64
s = input()
resault = base64.b64encode(bytes(s, 'utf-8')) #Шифровка
print(resault) 
print(base64.b64decode(resault)) #Дешифровка
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(base64.b64decode(resault).decode())
```

и лучше

```
resault = base64.b64encode(s.encode())
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!